MDX: Incorrect value using EXISTING
I am trying to use EXISTING to get the sum of multiple members being selected. Below is what I have. The MDX is not returning a syntax error but the numerical result is way off from what I need. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?
Case When
(BusinessUnit.CurrentMember is [BusinessUnit].&[1])

then
[Account].&[1443] + [Account].&[938] + [Account].&[1141] + [Account].&[1144] + [Account].&[1095] + ([Account].&[1440],[BusinessUnit].&[44]) + ([Account].&[1147],[BusinessUnit].&[44])

else
Sum (EXISTING [BusinessUnit].Members * {[Account].&[1443] , [Account].&[938] , [Account].&[1141] , [Account].&[1144] , [Account].&[1095] })

End
I tried the above syntax where [Business Unit].&[1] is the top level of the hierarchy. Below is one example of the variance I'm getting.
Correct Value: -58,638
Returned Value (based on syntax): 26,513,062

